# How do I draw a route between two LatLng objects in Android using the Google Maps Api?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm writting down an Android app where, at some point, I get two different locations as LatLng objects, and I can easily add two markers (one for each location) to my map.

The problem comes when I want to draw a route between these two markers, since I'm new to Android app development and I don't know how to do it. I'm just looking for some ideas or some code to make me understand how to do it.

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

1- Create list of latLng

```
ArrayList<LatLng> locList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
```

Fill this array with your locations

2- Add [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline) with `PolyLineOptions` and your list of locations

```
 mMap.addPolyline((new PolylineOptions()).addAll(locList )
            .width(5)
            .color(Color.RED)
            .geodesic(false));
```

Comment: Well. Thanks. It's pretty close to what I want, but it seems to just draw a straight line between the two markers, and I actually need a street route. You know what I mean? A route to do by foot through the streets.

Comment: Well, the question was "how to draw line between 2 points,"  so how it wouldn't be straight?

Comment: Well if you check it the actual question is "How to draw a route" not a line. Thanks anyway :)